# Visiblox Charting: Ruler Behavior for calculating delta values

Tags: charts, visiblox, rulers

Has anybody experience of working on RulerBehavior of Visiblox charting toolkit? I am looking for some delta finding examples. Visiblox forum does not contain any such information. So if anyone can share his/her experience.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delta values? 
As in Max value minus Min value?

Here is what I do:

```
double xMeasure = (double)MyRuler.MaxX - (double)MyRuler.MinX;
double yMeasure = (double)MyRuler.MaxY - (double)MyRuler.MinY;
```